# Qt and using an existing win32 dll

Tags: qt, dllexport

I want to do some development work using Qt. I have built several small apps and followed
some tutorials. All's fine and seems straight forward.

The development to be done involves using existing code that is contained in win32 dlls. I want to reuse this code with minimum fuss and link them into my Qt app. I have the headers, libs and the dlls so I'll be linking at compile time not dynamically at runtime.

I have tried to do this but Qt always complains always complains with link errors similar to:
main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_Add referenced in function _main

No matter how I tweak the .pro file it always complains.

I've spent many hours googling and found snippets of info. I could not find one answer that told the whole story. What I'm after is a set of steps, a tutorial like sequence that needs to be followed. There may even be an example in the Qt installation examples but I've been unable to find it.

Here is the simple 'knock-up' I've been trying to get to work in order to move on to the main development. It's based on the MS tutorial dll MathsFunc.

The win32 dll:

```
// Visual Studio 2005
//Funcs.h
#ifdef MATHFUNCS_EXPORTS
    #define MATHFUNCSDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define MATHFUNCSDLL_API __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {                    /* Assume C declarations for C++ */
#endif

// Returns a + b
MATHFUNCSDLL_API double Add(double a, double b); 

#ifdef __cplusplus
}                   /* Assume C declarations for C++ */
#endif

//Funcs.cpp
#include "Funcs.h"

double Add(double a, double b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

The Qt app that imports the dll.

```
//main.cpp
#include <QCoreApplication>

#include "../../mathfuncs/funcs.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    double dResult = Add(1.0,2.0);

    printf("1 + 2 = %f\n",dResult);

    return a.exec();
}
```

//The Qt project file .por

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2013-03-04T09:16:18
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET = Useit
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += c:/tmp/mathfuncs

HEADERS += c:/tmp/mathfuncs

LIBS += c:/tmp/mathfuncs/MathFuncs.lib
```

Thanks in advance for any input.

D.

Comment: Did you tried define __cplusplus in your .pro file?

Comment: If __cplusplus is defined in the dll project, then the extern "C" works, and the function is exported as a c function. If not defined in your Qt project, then your extern "C" does not work there, thus your Qt project will think it is a C++ function with name mangling.

Comment: I've tried using the header file with and without __cpluplus defined and get the same issues.